# how to load sharepoint.client assembly during run time in c#

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, .net-assembly

Hi I have ben trying to load sharepoint assembly during runtime, But i am always getting the error
"Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException' in mscorlib.dll
"

here i my code snippet

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(extension);
Type type = assembly.GetType("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File");
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Also if i wish to know all the method names then ho would i do it?

Please help!!!

Comment: Have you checked and verified, that the desired assembly is installed on the machine, where this code runs?

Comment: my goal is to install the libraries in ssis script task during runtime. I was running this code to test it. My dll files are located in my local file storage and i am loading the assmbly.load()

Answer (score 0):

You can get the exact contained types with Assembly.GetExportedTypes().

With Type.GetMethods() you can get all the methods of a type.

Comment: I am getting this erro Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime, Version=16.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: When i converted a NUPCKG format to dll using nuget cli , i got multiple dll files for sharepoint.client , In this case is it possibe that  wehn i am only loading "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" its denpendency which ight be in other folders are stopping from running it ? just a thought